# looping through images and displaying associated image details

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an edit page (for a car model) which loops through a list of images and display the description associated with each image in a text field where user can edit it.

My problem is that for each image, instead of displaying its associated description, all the descriptions associated with the car (and not that particular image) are displayed for each particular image. For e.g, if i have am editing a car details and this car has 3 images, each having a description. All 3 descriptions are displayed for each image, resulting in 9 descriptions field in all on my edit page.

```
<% @car.images.each do | image | %>
<div class="car_photos">
  <%= image_tag(image.data.url(:thumb), :alt => '') %>
     <% f.fields_for :images do |builder| %>
       <%= render "imageEdit", :f => builder %>
     <% end %>
</div>
<% end unless @car.images.first.new_record? rescue nil %>
```

_imageEdit.html.erb:

```
<% f.fields_for :descriptions do |builder| %>
<p>Description:<%= builder.text_area :desc %></p>
<% end %>
```

Any suggesion on how to solve this prob? Thanks

Comment: How are the descriptiones associated with images(do they have image id)?

Comment: you are looping twice for images, try to remove fist loop and see.

Comment: Yes, an image has many descriptions and a description belongs to an image. Each description has an image_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do

```
<% f.fields_for :images, image do |builder| %>
```

or

```
<% f.fields_for image do |builder| %>
```

Comment: <% f.fields_for :images, image do |builder| %> seems to do the work great!! Thanks a lot.